# I need to insert the bibitem based on the harvard reference style label

Tags: bibtex

Could anyone help me on this one.

```
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem" write$
  make.full.names duplicate$ label =
    'skip$
    { "{" label * "}" * write$ }
  if$
  "[" swap$ * "(" * write$
  year duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "????" }
    'skip$
  if$
  extra.label * ")]{" * write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}
```

I need the expected output is:

```
\bibitem[Ashkin \harvardand{} Dziedzic(1987)]{ashkin_science_1987}

\bibitem[Ashkin et~al.]{ashkin, Dziedzic, Bjorkholm \harvardand{} Chu}{1986}{ashkin_ol_1986}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The term "harvard reference style" is quite broad, but usually encompasses authoryear-style citation call-outs. Within the LaTeX sphere, `harvard` usually means a specific *package* which consists of (a) the file `harvard.sty` and (b) six or seven bibliography style files, such as `agsm.bst`, `dcu.bst`, and `kluwer.bst`. However, besides the "`harvard`" package, there are quite a few other LaTeX packages -- including `natbib` and `apa6` -- that can generate authoryear-style citation call-outs. Please tell us which bibliography style you use at the moment.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Do you intend to hack a specific bibliography style file? (If so, which one? `Harvard` is *not* the name of a bibliography style file.) And, what exactly do you intend to change: the citation call-out or the (formatted) bibliographic entry itself? What does the `\bibitem` information look like *before* the hack is administered?